# neoism how to parse query with "path" result

Tags: go, neo4j, neoism

I have this query:
match path =  (test:Test {t_name:"Test-1"})-[r*]->(child) return path

Json response:
results [1]
 - columns[1]
    - 0: path
 - data[6]
    - row[1]
    - meta[1]
    - graph
        - nodes[2]
        - relationships[1]

How to parse this query result in Neoism? I want to get the nodes and relationships in the response result.

Answer (score 0):

You can always return these from the query itself, instead of the path:

```
...
return nodes(path) as nodes, relationships(path) as relationships
```

Comment: My question is how to parse the results of the query. Your suggestion is just another way to get the same response. The path query I am using returns both the nodes as relationships already. How to parse the query response for the nodes and relationships?